# AngularJS syntax {name : data.id}

Tags: angularjs, syntax

I came across this code, {Id : data.registrant}, at my work and don't really understand what it does.  I also am not sure how to search for this on Google to get an answer to it.

```
function next(data) {
   var options = {Id: data.registrant};
   Nav.nextScreen(opts)
}
```

Apologies if this is a duplicate question.  Thanks.

Comment: This is called an object literal.

Comment: It set an object with `Id` property and a value from the `data` object that was passed to the function (`data.registrant`) to a variable named `options` and then pass an undefined (AFAIK) variable called `opts` (Not `options`, but `opts`, that perhaps was defined somewhere else) to a function `Nav.nextScreen`

Comment: Thanks to the both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "braces" are making an object literal, i.e. they create an object.

Those are Javascript objects.

Example:

```
function someFunc(arg) {
    alert(arg.foo);
    alert(arg.bar);
}

someFunc({foo: "This", bar: "works!"});
```

You can create the object beforehand has well:

```
var someObject = {
    foo: "This", 
    bar: "works!"
};

someFunc(someObject);
```